# Raiting как добавить отступы?

Tags: android

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:numStars="6"
    android:stepSize="1"
    style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Мои кастомные картинки расположенны очень близко к друг другу, как сделать чтобы можно было добавить отступы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получил [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_empty" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_empty" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_filled" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
```

Вот мой код

Comment: только программно, через код: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213784/spacing-between-the-stars-of-a-rating-bar  
Или через XML в drawable вашего элемента рейтинга

Comment: @metalurgus, а через xml в drawable это как, можно пример кода, я там не встречал такого параметра как отступ, width height если ток

Comment: через `layer-list`. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20drawable%20xml%20padding&es_th=1

Comment: @metalurgus, Попробовал что - то вообще не работает, картинку выше выложил

Comment: значит неправильно пробовали.

Comment: @metalurgus, код выложил тоже выше

Comment: @metalurgus, слушай а можно в drawable где я добавляю картинку, добавить еще linearLayout или какой нибудь компонент где и можно будет указать размер, в итоге получиться что якобы картинка с отступом.?

Comment: Просто сделай свои кружки с прозрачными полями по краям в половину отступа, который тебе нужен. Картинку шире, а кружок в ней меньше.

Comment: @pavlofff, тоесть саму картинку чтоли?, так не пойдет,  есть другой вариант?